# Apple Official iOS Development Certificate

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-inc

Are there any official certification programs by Apple for iOS App Development?

Comment: I have an Apple Swiss army Jackknife that I got for answering technical questions during a long gone era at Apple. No frameable "Certified Developer" certificates or the like. Never seen any.

Answer (score 4):

There are no iOS certifications currently listed on the Apple Developer web site.

The de-facto industry standard base-level certification is getting at least one non-trivial native Objective C (or Swift) app that you've developed approved by Apple into the iOS App store.

Answer (score 1):

Apple does now seem to offer a Swift Certification through CertiPort. Info can be found on the Apple developer site [here](https://developer.apple.com/learn/curriculum/)  and on the Certiport site [here](https://certiport.pearsonvue.com/Certifications/Apple/App-Dev-With-Swift/Overview.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Apple has hyperlinks to all of the topics they do provide certification for off of [this](http://training.apple.com/certification) page.  At this time it is only Mac OS X IT-related and 'Pro Apps', meaning Apple apps used by creative professionals/iWork.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of Apple-sanctioned certifications for software development. From the [Apple Certifications](http://training.apple.com/certification) page there are only two tracks - IT and Creative. Becoming an [Apple Developer](http://developer.apple.com/) gives you access to Apple material such as Tech Talk and WWDC sessions, but there is no official certification path as far as I can tell.

I have read wonderful things about training at the [Big Nerd Ranch](http://www.bignerdranch.com/) and at the [Pragmatic Studio](http://pragmaticstudio.com/), but I haven't experienced these courses myself (yet). Both of these places are well regarded in the community and while they do no not offer certifications per se, they still seem like terrific alternatives for training. Hope this helps.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but you might want to update because it looks like Pragmatic Studios might've dropped iOS - there is no mention on the page you link to and iOS seems to only be mentioned in past events and recommended books...

Answer (score 0):

While not available initially, Apple has recently partnered with a widely recognised, 3rd party training provider [LearnQuest](https://www.learnquest.com). LearnQuest claims to be an **Apple Authorised Global Training Provider**.

Clicking the Find a course button on [Apple Training website](https://training.apple.com/us/en) directs to the [Apple Authorized Training Schedule page](https://www.learnquest.com/schedule-custom.aspx?s20170128=y) on LearnQuest's website.

The [App Development Training Program](https://www.learnquest.com/search-results.aspx?categoryid=709&subcategoryid=4598) mentioned on LearnQuest lists the following training paths as of this writing:

- [Introduction to Swift 4](https://www.learnquest.com/course-detail-v3.aspx?cnum=APL-DEV100-040-IN).
- [Introduction to the iOS 11 SDK](https://www.learnquest.com/course-detail-v3.aspx?cnum=APL-DEV105-110-IN).
- [App Development with Swift 4](https://www.learnquest.com/course-detail-v3.aspx?cnum=APL-DEV110-110-IN).

All three of them are classroom courses. These courses are targeted towards Software Developers, Software Architects and Technology Consultants.

**Note:** The hyperlinks mentioned in the answer direct to the courses available in the current country of my residence. You may need to switch to the desired country page on LearnQuest's website.